# Receiving error when trying to connect to MySql

Tags: mysql

I receive the following error when trying to connect to mySql through phpmyadin:

MySQL said:

```
1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

I was able to set the password for localhost using the console. I also set the password in the config.inc.php file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have changed password for Mysql but not updated password on PHP Myadmin config file .